# New site design!

Tags: discussion, design

[image]

Congratulations! As you can see, the new site design just went live.

We have also themed the Twitter account and newsletter template for this site, and adjusted the privilege levels to higher thresholds.

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with **design** and **bug**.

Congrats again and thank you for being an awesome community!

Oh! And by the way, we have also updated your Chat theme!

Comment: W0W Thanks for all :")

Comment: good work @Hynes

Comment: Wow, so cool! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: great!!! enjoying new design ;)

Comment: Looks awesome ,, Thanks a ton.....:-)

Comment: fabulous ,, thanks for new look get bored from old one... :)

Comment: Thanks Stackexchange, looks great!

Comment: Love it.  Great work guys.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, great work!!

Comment: It looks amazing! Great work!!

Comment: Awesome job long life to the helmet!!

Comment: Woooot! Looks great!

Comment: Great to see Magento SE finally get it's own skin! Looking great!

Comment: Love this hexagon shaped stuff ))

Comment: twitter account you say?

Comment: @Sally interesting find

Comment: @JulienLachal https://twitter.com/stackmagento

Comment: @Sally I wrote the post and Adam posted it on my behalf once he had finished setting the new design up. :)

Comment: Sure, but the sockpuppet theory sounds a lot more likely. :) (I thought we updated network profiles on post ownership change, but guess not? I'll look... eventually.)

Comment: Excellent job. I love how Magento it separates us from the rest of the SO community.

Answer (score 9):

**This is complain/suggestion from user perspective.**

I have a little complain, due to too brightness, my eyes are getting tired and have to leave the site.

I wonder if there are people like me.

This background image is too bright, and cannot stay at top too long. http://cdn.sstatic.net/magento/img/background-header-magento.png?v=159f37a58acc

Comment: I can relate to this tbh

Comment: I'm color blind, this does not affect me :).

Comment: @adarsh — if it's something you feel strongly about, I would suggest starting a new post tagged as [tag:discussion] and [tag:design]. We can talk about the issue more fully there. :)

Comment: Here http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/852/top-bar-too-bright-my-eyes-are-getting-tired

Comment: I personally love the orange, also its Magento it had to be orange :) That said, it is pretty bright. I can see how it could affect some people.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, looks awesome, good job, nicely done!