# Top bar too bright, my eyes are getting tired

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

First of all, this new design is really awesome. I would like to thank all of the team member who made it possible.

I am creating this post because @Hynes suggested to [New site design!](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/835/new-site-design/839?noredirect=1#comment3177_839)

**This is feedback/suggestion from user perspective on colour.**

I have a little complain, due to too brightness, my eyes are getting tired and cannot stay longer at top of the site.

I wonder if there are people like me.

I am referring to this background image, it is too bright, and cannot stay at top longer. http://cdn.sstatic.net/magento/img/background-header-magento.png?v=159f37a58acc

Comment: a little red/green blind here. It is fine for me, although I'm not much at the site currently :-/

Comment: +1. Even I feel the same. It's eye stretching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your thoughts here. Orange is one of the those tricky colors, like red, in that when you mute the saturation it can quickly become "muddied" in its appearance. That said, I still think there's something we could do here.

Below is an alternate image. Is this still too bright? I've tried to level out the "hot" red areas with a more even orange tone.

[image]

---

**UPDATE:** The header image above has replaced the previous "hot red orange" header image.

Comment: Yeah, it's more better for me now. I think it was red causing more stress to my eyes.

Comment: I reckon it also mainly depends on your screen brightness and color display. I've got three different screens, one of them is older than the two others, and the red pops up more on the old screen.